# Adding New Table in Product Entity ax 2012 r2 DMF/DIXF

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

Can some one please help me with Steps for Adding new table in Product Entity. I have a table `msftInventTable`

```
msftInventTable where msftInventTable.InventTable == InventTable.Recid;
```

Along with importing data into Product, InventTables I would like to import data into this table too using **Product Entity**.

Can someone please help me with the steps to do? I tried to add it in the query and tried with adding fields in Staging and all steps, but i dont understand what i am missing. I am unable to import data into this table. So Temporarily, i have used coding in insertUpdate  method to import data. But this will impact performance , so I need some inputs.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a programming question since Microsoft have a wizard for creating custom entities.

1. Create a *new entity* called msftInventTable. You don't have to create code for this. In the "Data import export framework" module under Common there is a function called "Create a Custom entity for data import/export".
2. Follow the wizard for your custom table. All the DMF classes, tables and setup is created automatically.
3. Add your custom msftInventTable entity to the same *processing group* as your Product entity:
   [image: Entities for a processing group]
4. Setup the new entity and run the import for the processing group.

Comment: Thanks for reply . Yes I am aware of creating entity for custom table. But doing like what you said, i will have a new entity and i need another excel sheet for loading this right. What I asked is that , i would like to add a table in the same Product entity instead of creating a new entity.